# Issue getting executable directory with .NET core?

Tags: c#, .net

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'C:\Users\admin\development\project31\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\resources\logging\debug.log'.'

This happens on the following line...

```
var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(executionPath + "/resources/logging/" + file, true);
```

Full code:

```
private static void LogToFile(string file, string content)
{
    var executionPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(executionPath + "/resources/logging/" + file, true);

    fileWriter.WriteLine(content);
    fileWriter.Close();
}
```

The issue is, its going into the `netcoreapp2.0` folder, when all I want it to go into is the debug.

I could just back up 1 directory, but I know if I use this code in .NET framework not .NET core it will break again due to .NET framework not running debug in netcoreapp2.0

Comment: Does this directory exists ? If you open file explorer and you go to the folder _C:\Users\admin\development\project31\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\resources_ do you see there any folder with the name logging?

Comment: The issue is, its going into the `netcoreapp2.0` folder, when all I want it to go into is the debug folder. But I know if I just back 1 directory, when I use this code in .NET framework not .NET core it will break again.

Comment: That you want is to access a file in a directory. If the directory does not exist, you would get a _System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException_. So the question you should first answer, is if this directory exists.

Comment: @zades: That's simply not how .NET Core builds things - the output path includes the target framework (for which I'm personally very grateful). That can easily be found by having a look in the directory in question. It's not really clear *why* you'd need it to be in bin/Debug to start with. Perhaps you should be configuring the directory in a different way? (I wouldn't want any important output in a `bin` directory which I'd regard as transient, to be deleted whenever I want to do a clean build...)